# copy_to field referring parent field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is my mapping of Product document type. I have `"copy_to" : "product_all"` in mapping.
I am expecting value of label in brand should be copied in 'product_all' in product. Is it correct way of referring the field in outer object from inner object i.e. (`product_all` in type product from brand), below mapping doesn't work as I don't get results back for a query made on `product_all` field for the value of label in brand. Am I missing something?

```
{
  "product": {
    "_timestamp": {
      "enabled": true,
      "store": true
    },
    "_all": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "properties": {
      "brand": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "label": {
            "type": "multi_field",
            "fields": {
              "label": {
                "type": "string",
                "index_analyzer": "productAnalyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "productAnalyzer"
              },
              "raw": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            },
            "copy_to": "product_all"
          }
        }
      },
      "product_all": {
        "type": "string",
        "index_analyzer": "productAnalyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "productAnalyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved "copy_to":"product_all"  inside label.label of mutifield. Now it works

```
"label": {
            "type": "multi_field",
            "fields": {
              "label": {
                "type": "string",
                "copy_to": "product_all"
                "index_analyzer": "productAnalyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "productAnalyzer"
              },
              "raw": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }

          }
```